# VBA code to delete a row based on a date greater than a user inputed variable

Tags: vba, date

I have a list of data that needs to have some of the rows deleted based on two criteria.  The first criteria is that there needs to be a zero in the 5th column.  The second criteria are that the date in field 3 needs to be greater than the user input variable collected earlier on the form.  If both of those criteria's are met then the row should be deleted.  If I comment out the second criteria the rows that match the first criteria delete correctly, so I know it is related to the dates.  I also made sure the user inputted variable and the dates on the spreadsheet are the same format.
Here is the code

```
Dim PYE As Date
Dim vQuestion
vQuestion = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the plan year end date?")
If IsDate(vQuestion) Then
PYE = DateValue(vQuestion)
Else
MsgBox "Invalid date"
End If
If vQuestion = "False" Then Exit Sub



 With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlAnd
   .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & PYE
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

I have been googling this for a while and am coming up with no progress, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA needs dates defined by #MM/DD/YYYY#.  Not necessarily in that format, but definitely with the # signs before and after the date.  Have you tried sticking those in your formula?

Possibly:

```
AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">#" & PYE & "#"
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  I hade tried putting the # around PYE but I didn't think about putting it where you did.  Thank you

Comment: Please give my answer the "Accepted Answer" checkmark, if you don't mind.  I'd appreciate it greatly!  :o)